# Disk database cleanup during reorg, where in Go-Ethereum (or other node codebase) does that happen?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, server-side

I'm curious about how the discarded "oldchain" during reorg also has its data cleaned up from the disk drive database. I'm unable to see anything about that in the reorg method in core/blockchain.go. Not sure where to look for it exactly. It seems convenient to do it block for block using the trie roots in the headers.